# Ball bounce Java Problems

Tags: java

So, I'm a total Java newb and I wanted to make an animation program but I wanted to do it my own way so I understand how it works, I know there may be other questions like this but I wanted to know the answer using the code I made, so here is my code, the problem is when I run this the box doesn't show up on the window and looking at my prints it stops right before i set the color. Can anyone help?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
final public class main extends JFrame{
    private int x = 20;
    private int y = 20;

    private boolean right = true;
    private boolean left = false;
    private boolean down = true;
    private boolean up = false;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame JFrame = new JFrame("On My Own (kinda)");
        JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JFrame.setVisible(true);
        JFrame.setLocation(375, 55);
        JFrame.setSize(300, 300);
        new main().Animate();
    }

    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("2");
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        System.out.println("3");
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        System.out.println("4");
        g.fillRect(x, y, 6, 6);
        System.out.println("5");
    }

    public void Animate(){
        System.out.println("1");
        while(true){
            //Game loop
            if(x >= 283){
                right = false;
                left = true;
            }
            if(x <= 7){
                right = true;
                left = false;
            }
            if(y >= 259){
                up = true;
                down = false;
            }
            if(y <= 7){
                up = false;
                down = true;
            }
            if(up){
                y--;
            }
            if(down){
                y++;
            }
            if(left){
                x--;
            }
            if(right){
                x++;
            }
            try{
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception exc){System.out.println("OOOPS");}
            draw();
        }
    }

}
```

And this is what I get

```
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.draw(main.java:30)
    at main.Animate(main.java:71)
    at main.main(main.java:23)
2
3
```

Comment: I don't see a question here... What are those magic numbers btw?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work .. why?

Comment: `I know there may be other questions like this` - then why don't you check those out first and ask _specific_ questions when you have problems with your code? Don't make us explain your code to you.

Comment: Can't tell what's the bigger problem: Your ignorance of Java or physics of bouncing balls.

Comment: Didnt expect awnsers this fast, sorry i edited the post to have the erros, the box doesnt show up in theJFrame

Comment: What's line 30? Your example output it is in method `draw()` but before printing `2` - which is right the first line of what you posted.

Comment: What is `getGraphics()`?